# jquery mobile page transition is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have this

```
            $.mobile.changePage( "mainmenu.php", { 
                transition: "slide",
                reverse: true
            });
```

to change pages using a slide, but when I test on my desktop or my phone, it just changes pages instantly without a slide...

Does anyone know whats wrong?

Comment: How are you loading jQuery mobile? From a CDN or locally? Make sure you have all the CSS and JS files available. I am assuming you tested it across multiple browsers to make sure it isn't a browser-specific issue.

Comment: I am loading using online link, not local files, and I only tested in browser firefox 35, and cell phone google chrome.

Comment: Odd. I see you are loading a php file. What I would try is loading the application in Chrome or Firefox with the respective developer tools open. See if it is doing a complete page reload when that javascript is run. Also make sure that you haven't accidentally set the default transitions to none. When you say it just changes instantly, does it fade at all? That would be indicative of a CSS issue. Finally, see if you can get slide transitions through other means, such as via an <a> link such as <a href="index.html" data-transition="slide">Slide</a>